# I can't use the add menu, how can I fix it?

Tags: modeling, geometry

I'm starting now to modelling in blender, I was trying to create an hexagon, as everyone do, I searched on YouTube and here I understood that you need to do 3 simple steps:

1. Add a cylinder
2. Click on the menu in the left bottom part of the screen
3. Reduce the number of vertices

And the magic is done, but for some reason my add menu doesn't work properly, as you can see in the photo it seems impossible to change the properties and the first time i click on it, it disapears!
[image]

Comment: you need to make sure that Global Undo is enabled in Preferences > System

Comment: It works, but this change remains ot at the next boot of blender I need to select this option again?

Comment: it should be enabled by default, so what you can do is open a new file, go in the Preferences, enable Global Undo, then File > Defaults > Save Startup File

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As moonboots told me the problem is that the Global Undo was disabled, to fix the problem you need to go here: Edit->Preferences->System and add the check on the Global undo